# How do I send an email to my python server?

Tags: python, email, smtp

I've written a small smtp server in python (taken from the [smtpd docs](https://pymotw.com/2/smtpd/#)):

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class MySMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)
        return

server = MySMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 587), None)

asyncore.loop()
```

I want to be able to send an email from my gmail account (or whatever email provider) to this server. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Write an MX record on an A-Level domain
2. Throw the server up on a box that has port 587 opened
3. Send an email from gmail to someone@myaleveldomain.com
4. Profit?

Step 4 hasn't really come through. I can't find any logs that offer any info into what happened, according to my server logs the message from gmail never arrived.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a DNS error which isn't really on-topic for Stack Overflow and impossible to debug without details.

Comment: are you sure? im waiting for an answer that has a bit more know-how behind it

Comment: No, your question is too vague to be sure. If you don't see any logs then presumably GMail didn't find your MX or was unable to connect, but without seeing them, we can't say really. And merely printing to stdout doesn't log anything per se.